# "With what [...]?" or "What [...] with?"

Tags: grammar, prepositions, questions, whom

Making a comparison with Who/Whom I now have a question about the use of what with prepositions in questions. I'll explain by example:

These two sentences are correct, one is more formal than the other:

**Who/Whom**

- Formal: **With whom** are you doing that?
- Informal: **Who** are you doing that **with**?

But if I substitute Who/Whom with What, the "formal" one sounds a bit awkward and I'm not sure if it's correct or not:

**What**

- **With what** are you doing that?
- **What** are you doing that **with**?

So, are those last two questions grammatically correct?
Is one more formal than the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are both grammatical, but *With what are you doing that?* is much more formal, and probably quite rare.

Answer (score -1):

"Who are you doing that with?" is not correct.  "With" is a preposition, and prepositions take objects.  "Who" is subjective, and "whom" is objective.  Therefore, one must use "whom" in a prepositional phrase.

"With what are you doing that?" and "What are you doing that with?" are both correct.  Ending a sentence with a preposition is not incorrect, but including a preposition without its object is.

"With what..." is the more formal of the two.

Comment: 'Who are you doing that with?' is doubtless far more common than 'Whom are you doing that with?' and probably more common than 'With whom are you doing that?' [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Who+are+you+going+with%2CWhom+are+you+going+with%2CWith+whom+are+you+going&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CWho%20are%20you%20going%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CWhom%20are%20you%20going%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CWith%20whom%20are%20you%20going%3B%2Cc0) reflect this.

Comment: So it's not a case of 'must'. It has been mentioned in other ELU threads that 'whom' is slowly disappearing from the English lexicon.